# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{mn^2+m^2n+2mn}$

Tags: summation

Evaluate :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{mn^2+m^2n+2mn}$$

My try :

[image]

Some of the terms are getting cancelled out but the rest are not

Comment: I can't read this.  Take the trouble to type it out, please.

Comment: You've been here far more than long enough to know that you need to type things like this in MathJax. Your older posts show that you do know how to use MathJax, and that this is not the first time you've been told to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea that can help:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{mn^2+m^2n+2mn}& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m(m+n+2)}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+2)}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+n+2}\right]\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+2)}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+4}\right)+\dotsb\right]\\
&\text{the expression inside the inner parentheses is actually a $\color{red}{\text{finite}}$ sum}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+2)}\left[1+\frac{1}{2}+\dotsb +\frac{1}{n+2}\right]\\
& =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\left[1+\frac{1}{2}+\dotsb +\frac{1}{n+2}\right]\\
& =\frac{1}{2} \left[\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\dotsb\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)+\dotsb}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{11}{6}+\frac{25}{24}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)+\dotsb}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{11}{6}+\frac{25}{24}+\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4 \cdot 5}+\frac{1}{5 \cdot 6}+ \dotsb\right)}+\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{3 \cdot 5}+\frac{1}{4 \cdot 6}\dotsb \right)}\right]
\end{align*}
Observe that the series in red and blue are telescoping series. That can be summed as 
$$\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+a)}=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+a}\right)$$
Hopefully now you can finish it.